# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'var'

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, elementor

I am receieving the following error when my site loads:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'var'

I am using Elementor and it has something to do with the admin-ajax.php

[image]

Does anyone know how to rectify this error. Many thanks.

Comment: I suspect the problem is with the `var patt` line, which ends in a dangling `=`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your code/commands and errors as **text** rather than as a screenshot. On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see _[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500)_ and _[Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)_ for why. For instructions on formatting see _[How do I format my code blocks?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)_. A [mre] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See _[ask]_.

Comment: use `/\d/` to capture digit-only

Answer (score 1):

It has to due with the "patt" variable at line 3034. Your slashes are commenting out everything so the browser sees this:

```
var patt = 
var result = oldUrl.match(patt);
```

Answer (score 0):

JS expects a value after equal sign which is not given. Your problem will be solved when you uncomment [0-9] at line 3034

```
var patt = [0-9];
```

Comment: That makes sense, many thanks. This code is contained in the index. Any idea about how to access it?

Comment: What do you mean by accessing?